# Calculating counts over several columns in DB

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-performance

We have a product backed by a DB (currently Oracle, planning to support MS SQL Server as well) with several dozen tables. For simplicity let's take one table called TASK.

We have a use case when we need to present the user the number of tasks having specific criteria. For example, suppose that among many columns the TASK table has, there are 3 columns suitable for this use case:

- PRIORITY- possible values LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH
- OWNER - possible values are users registered in the system (can be 10s)
- STATUS- possible values IDLE, IN_PROCESS, DONE

So we want to display the user exactly how many tasks are LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH, how many of them are owned by some specific user, and how many pertain to different statuses. Of course the basic implementation would be to maintain these counts up-to-date, on every modification to the TASK table. However what complicates the matter is the fact that the user can additionally filter the result by some criteria that can include (or not) part of the columns mentioned above.

*For example, the use might want to see those counts only for tasks that are owned by him and have been created last month. The number of possible filter combinations is endless here, so needless to say maintaining up-to-date counts is impossible.*

**So the question is: how this problem can be solved without serious impact on the DB performance?** Can it be solved solely over DB, or should we resort to using other data stores, like sparse data store? It feels like a problem that is present allover in many companies. For example in Amazon store, you can see the counts on categories while using arbitrary text search criteria, which means that they also calculate it on the spot instead of maintaining it up-to-date all the time.

One last thing: we can accept a certain functional limitation, saying that the count should be exact up to 100, but starting from 100 it can just say "over 100 tasks". Maybe this mitigation can allow us to emit more efficient SQL queries.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you would like to have info about 3 different distributions: across PRIORITY, OWNER and STATUS. I suppose the best way to solve this problem is to maintain 3 different data sources (like SQL query, aggregated info in DB or Redis, etc.).

The simplest way to calculate this data I see as build separate SQL query for each distribution. For example, for priority it would something like:

```
SELECT USER_ID, PRIORITY, COUNT(*)
FROM TASKS
[WHERE <additional search criterias>]
GROUP BY PRIORITY
```

Of course, it is not the most efficient way in terms of database performance but it allows to maintain counts up to date.

If you would like to store aggregated values which may significantly decrease database loads (it depends on rows count) so you probably need to build a cube which dimensions should be available search criteria. With this approach, you may implement limitation functionality.

Comment: Thanks Max. This is of course the naive approach we already tested. The problem is - the performance of this is dire. Not only it takes considerable time for such a query to finish, this of course affects other users that perform other simple queries over DB. So I was looking for creative approaches to solve this problem that would somehow distribute this load in a more unified way across time.